# Pivot table on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, pivot, multiple-columns

I have a query that gives me this result:

```
|SystemName    |SystemDescription   |CertificateType |CertName  |CertDate  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ABC          |Blah-blah ABC       | X             | X-865567  | 1 Jan    |
| ABC          |Blah-blah ABC       | Y             | Y-8a5567  | 2 Jan    |
| ABC          |Blah-blah ABC       | Z             | Z-86af67  | 3 Jan    |
| EFG          |Blah-blah EFG       | X             | X-8kuhkj  | 4 Jan    |
| EFG          |Blah-blah EFG       | Y             | Y-uiiou   | 5 Jan    |
| EFG          |Blah-blah EFG       | Z             | Z-8lkjhu  | 6 Jan    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to produce this result:

```
|SystemName |SystemDescription   | X-Name  | X-Date | Y-Name | Y-Date | Z-Name | Z-Date|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ABC        | Blah-blah ABC      |X-865567 | 1 Jan  |Y-8a5567| 2 Jan  |Z-86af67| 3 Jan |
|EFG        | Blah-blah EFG      |X-8kuhkj | 4 Jan  |Y-uiiou | 5 Jan  |Z-8lkjhu| 6 Jan |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In other words I need to pivot without aggregation and with at least 2 columns not pivoted. 
Is it possible to produce this without functions, stored procedures and temp tables?? I know how to easily implement this with a few funcitons, I can come up with solution with temp table.

I wonder if it is possible to get a neat solution using PIVOT??

p.s. this is not a homework, just a brain-teaser -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `PIVOT` to do this, sometimes it's more of a mess to use it than it's worth. As far as not using aggregate functions - think about it, you want to group your records in terms of `SystemName` and `SystemDescription`, you don't have a choice but to use aggregates. That's ok though, just use `MAX` as I have done, you're going to get the results you want. The only thing you would need to worry about is in the scenario where there are two records with same `SystemName`, `SystemDescription` and `CertificationType` that have different values for `CertName` or `CertDate` - in that case you need some way to choose which attributes are selected for the group.

Here is a non-Pivot example:

```
SELECT SystemName,
       SystemDescription,
       MAX([x-Name]) AS [x-Name],
       MAX([x-Date]) AS [x-Date],
       MAX([y-Name]) AS [y-Name],
       MAX([y-Date]) AS [y-Date],    
       MAX([z-Name]) AS [z-Name],
       MAX([z-Date]) AS [z-Date]
FROM (
    SELECT SystemName, 
           SystemDescription,
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'X' THEN CertName END AS [x-Name],
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'Y' THEN CertName END AS [y-Name],
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'Z' THEN CertName END AS [z-Name],
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'X' THEN CertDate END AS [x-Date],
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'Y' THEN CertDate END AS [y-Date],
           CASE CertificationType WHEN 'Z' THEN CertDate END AS [z-Date]
    FROM @yourTable
) T
GROUP BY SystemName, SystemDescription;
```

Comment: A-ha! I knew there could be a very simple way! Thank you!

Comment: Took a bit of fiddling and CTE statement to get it right, but the idea is the same! Thanks again!